# Filezilla Connect through PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a file from my machine (client side) to the FileZilla server (server side) I have for storing the web page files. 
When trying to connect to FileZilla through PHP I receive the following error message:

```
Connection failed: Connection refused
```

Usually, I would expect the error when the login credentials are incorrect, however, in this case, they are correct.

My question: Can you connect to FileZilla via PHP? I am sure the answer must be 'Yes' however due to the technical difficulties currently I would not be surprised otherwise.

Potentially there is an error in the formatting of the connection function.

```
var $host = "xx.xx.xx.xx";
var $user = "xx";
var $pass = "xx";
var $connect;

function serverConnection()
{
    $conection = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass) or die
    ("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    } else {
        $this->connect = $conection;
    }
    return $this->connect;
}
```

The goal is to be able to upload files from a form to FileZilla, to act as users profile pictures.

Comment: Why are you using `mysqli_connect()` to connect to an FTP server?

Comment: try port `21` ...

Comment: What are the alternatives? I do see that mysqli_connect is wrong now though - I was reusing the code from my database connection

Comment: For FTP connections, you should be using [FTP functions](http://php.net/ftp_connect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you're using `mysqli_connect` which connects to a database server, you need to connect to an FTP server, so you should use the `FTP` functions. You should first [connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php) and then [login](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-login.php).

It should look something like this:

```
$server = 'myServer';
$user = 'myUsername';
$pass = 'myPassword';

$connect = ftp_connect($server) or die('Could not connect to FTP-server.');

if(ftp_login($connect, $user, $pass)) {
  echo 'Connected to FTP-server.';
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, now it is attempting to connect correctly, however, is being prompt by the 'die' message as opposed to connecting. For FileZilla is there extra steps before connecting e.g. change settings etc. The login credentials are correct